# Python declaring multiple values in a single variable in a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, boolean

I'm trying to call the values that I have inputted into the function solvable. It's not returning a boolean value in response to the input. This is my code:

```
class CramersRule:
   a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3, d1, d2, d3 = eval(input("Please enter values a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3, d1, d2, d3 of a simultaneous eq: "))
   def __init__(self):
      self.__a1 = a1
      self.__a2 = a2
      self.__a3 = a3
      self.__b1 = b1
      self.__b2 = b2
      self.__b3 = b3
      self.__c1 = c1
      self.__c2 = c2
      self.__c3 = c3
      self.__d1 = d1
      self.__d2 = d2
      self.__d3 = d3   

    def isSolvable(self, a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3, d1, d2, d3):
        if (a1*b2*c3 - a1*b3*c2 -a2*b1*c3 + a2*b3*c1 + a3*b1*c2 - a3*b2*c1) != 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

The `isSolvable()` function is supposed to return `False` if the method calculates the value to be 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to Stack Overflow!

Try this.

```
class CramersRule:
    def __init__(self):
        a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3, d1, d2, d3 = eval(input("Please enter values a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3, d1, d2, d3 of a simultaneous eq: "))
        self.__a1 = a1
        self.__a2 = a2
        self.__a3 = a3
        self.__b1 = b1
        self.__b2 = b2
        self.__b3 = b3
        self.__c1 = c1
        self.__c2 = c2
        self.__c3 = c3
        self.__d1 = d1
        self.__d2 = d2
        self.__d3 = d3

    def isSolvable(self):
        if (self.__a1*self.__b2*self.__c2 - self.__a1*self.__b3*self.__c2 -self.__a2*self.__b1*self.__c3 + self.__a2*self.__b3*self.__c1 + self.__a3*self.__b1*self.__c2 - self.__a3*self.__b2*self.__c1) != 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

I'm not sure how or where you're running your function but I was able to save the code to a file name `fq.py` and this is how I verified it in the python repl.

```
>python
>>>import fq
```

Next create an instance of the CramersRule class and assign it to a variable f. Also input the numbers at the prompt.

```
>>>f = fq.CramersRule()
```

Finally, see if it's true or false based on the numbers you input.

```
>>>f.isSolvable()
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much! But is there a method so it prompts the user to enter the variables from the input statement and use the function from there?

Comment: Yes, it can be run from a commend line without using the python repl. 
Add the following to the bottom of the fq.py file
`f = CramersRule()` then `print(f"Solveable? {f.isSolvable()}")`
Then to call the entire python script from your shell `>python fq.py`. Good luck!